# Detached a volume from an instance - what now?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I had an Amazon EC2 instance with EBS only disk - 8 GB disk. I needed some more space so I increased the volume to 320 GB. Then, I no longer needed all that space so I wanted to decrease the volume, but saw that it is impossible to decrease a volume size. So, I detached the volume, created a new volume with 32 GB, and attached it to my instance. However, now my instance does not start. When I try to start it from the console, it remains stopped. So, my questions are:

- What should I do to start my instance?
- What is the correct way to decrease a volume instance?

Comment: *"What should I do to start my instance?"*  Did you put the old volume back?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I tried to, but it only lets me add it as "sdf" to "sdp", while the instance apparently looks for it as "sda".

Comment: Detach the new volume.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I used AWS, but I can suggest you:

1. Create a snapshot of your original volume.
2. Create a new root volume of desired size
3. Create a volume from the snapshot
4. Move the data from the snapshot volume to the new volume
5. Delete the volume created from the snapshot , but keep the snapshot, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

For me Creating a new volume of required size and migrating the existing data is the right way to save the storage cost you are not using, as I don't think there is another way to reduce the size of the original volume.
You can refer the below links for the detailed steps on how to Reduce/ Increase the size of the EBS volume and check what is that you have missed-:

https://n2ws.com/blog/how-to-guides/how-to-reduce-the-size-of-an-ebs-volume

https://n2ws.com/blog/how-to-guides/how-to-increase-the-size-of-an-aws-ebs-cloud-volume-attached-to-a-linux-machine